# Is it possible to remove buildings drawn in Mapbox and replace them with other buildings?

Tags: mapbox

Is it possible to remove buildings drawn in Mapbox and replace them with other buildings? That is, when the map is in 3d, I want to delete one small building and place a big building instead[image]

Is it possible to remove this building and replace it with a large building?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE ! You can add more context like screenshots or links to support your post and help other users to be sure about what you need, it helps in general to have answers and better, good answers.

Comment: If you have some unique field for that single building you can just filter it out using the various filter functions - you will have to make sure that you maintain any filters for the 3D buildings already in the mapbox style.